# NaNs produced using Betareg

Tags: r

When trying to perform a Beta regression on the dataset below i get following error.
Can anyone tell me how to deal with this error?

thanks in advance

```
Error in quantile.default(x$residuals) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt(v * (1 - hatvalues(object))) : NaNs produced
```

code

```
model.beta = betareg(Percentage ~ Kuikenweek,data = dieet)
summary(model.beta)
```

data

```
Jaar    Kuikenweek  Percentage  Locatie
2013    Week 1  0,4238  Markenje
2013    Week -1 0,8248  Markenje
2013    Week 2  0,5927  Markenje
2013    Week -2 0,3208  Markenje
2013    Week 3  0,8317  Markenje
2013    Week -3 0,7314  Markenje
2014    Week 1  0,4624  Markenje
2014    Week 2  0,5224  Markenje
2014    Week -2 0,3528  Markenje
2014    Week 3  0,7739  Markenje
2014    Week -3 0,1264  Markenje
2015    Week -1 0,4516  Markenje
2015    Week -2 0,4306  Markenje
2015    Week -3 0,5243  Markenje
2013    Week 1  0,5117  Scheelhoek
2013    Week -1 0,1490  Scheelhoek
2013    Week 2  0,3342  Scheelhoek
2013    Week -2 0,5069  Scheelhoek
2013    Week 3  0,7101  Scheelhoek
2013    Week -3 0,8019  Scheelhoek
2013    Week 4  0,7569  Scheelhoek
2013    Week 5  0,9096  Scheelhoek
2013    Week 6  0,9013  Scheelhoek
2014    Week 1  0,5403  Scheelhoek
2014    Week -1 0,2264  Scheelhoek
2014    Week 2  0,5775  Scheelhoek
2014    Week 3  0,7366  Scheelhoek
2014    Week -3 0,4086  Scheelhoek
2014    Week 4  0,5750  Scheelhoek
2014    Week 5  0,6623  Scheelhoek
2015    Week 1  0,7758  Scheelhoek
2015    Week -1 0,1517  Scheelhoek
2015    Week 2  0,7587  Scheelhoek
2015    Week -2 0,3247  Scheelhoek
2015    Week 3  0,7463  Scheelhoek
2015    Week -3 0,6325  Scheelhoek
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so others can help you in better way.

Comment: How did you import this data? What is `class(dieet$Percentage)`? See [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Sharing a `dput()` is better than raw data because it's not clear how you imported the data into R.

Comment: Kuikenweek  = Chicken Week? It looks like commas are used for a decimal.  The value after week seems to be the chronological week.  So get rid if the word *Week* and just use the number after that word.  Make sure R is reading your percentage correctly.  It should be a number not a string.  Week should be a number, not a string.

Comment: Sorry for the bad structure of my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I reproduce your error here:

```
# here are the data
devtools::source_gist("169bfa3a6c709fd2fd31c5bfa46648ee")
library(betareg)
# fix percentages 
dieet$Percentage <- gsub(",",".",dieet$Percentage)
dieet$Percentage <- as.numeric(dieet$Percentage)
model.beta = betareg(Percentage ~ Kuikenweek,data = dieet)
summary(model.beta)
## Error in quantile.default(x$residuals) : 
##  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
## In addition: Warning message:
## In sqrt(v * (1 - hatvalues(object))) : NaNs produced
```

The problem arises because the default residual type "sweighted2" is not working for your model. So:

```
summary(model.beta, type = "deviance")
```

at least gets you the summary. There are several types of residuals available and which one is best for your purposes is more of a statistical question.